# How to remove the first row from multiple dataframes?

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

I have multiple dataframes and would like to remove the first row in all of them.

I have tried using a for loop but cannot understand what I am doing wrong

```
for (i in cities){

i <- i[-1, ]

}
```

I get the following error code:

> Error in i[-1, ] : incorrect number of dimensions

Comment: What is the class of "cities" ? Please provide reproducible example data.

Comment: Have tried it both as a list of 33 chr and a vector chr [1:33]

Comment: I got it from the global environment with:

cities <- as.list(objects())

and 

cities <- as.vector(objects())

Comment: Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: The result of `objects()` is just a character vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we assume that the only objects in your workspace are dataframes then this might succeed:

```
cities <- objects() )
for (i in cities) { assign(i, get(i)[-1,])}
```

Explanation:

Two thing wrong with original codes:

One was already mentioned in comments. "df" is not the same as `df`. You need to use `get` to convert a character value to a "true" R name that is used to retrieve an object having that name. The result of `object()` is only a character value.  In R the term "name" means a "language object". See the help page: `?mode`. (There is potential confusion about rownames and columnnames which are always "character"-class.) It's not like SAS which is a macro language that has no such distinction.

The second error was trying to get substitution for the `i` on the left-hand side of `<-`. The would have failed even if you were working with actual R names. The `assign` function is designed to handle character values that are then converted to R names.

Comment: Thank you that works! Could you explain me what I was doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

say you get a list of all the tables in your environment, and you call that list `cities`. You can't just iterate over each value of `cities` and change things, because in the list they are just characters.

Here is what you need:

```
for (i in cities){
 tmp <- get(i)    # load the actual table
 tmp <- tmp[-1, ] # remove first column
 assign(i, tmp)   # re-assign table to original table name
}
```